# Very fast way to do a coordinate frame transform

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I need a function that rotates and translates a huge amount of line segments.

For example, I have a set of line segments in the form `{{x0,y0,z0},{x1,y1,z1}}`

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20000, 2, 3}]
```

and three vectors

```
n = {n1,n2,n3}
s = {s1,s2,s3} (* Orthogonal to n *)
p = {p1,p2,p3}
```

I want to perform a rigid (right handed) transformation that sends `p` to the origin, `n` to the $z$ axis and $s$ to the $y$ axis, in order to apply it to `data`.

I know about `RotationMatrix`, `RotationTransform`, and I have coded a (very ugly) solution but, due to inexperience and the amount of data, I'm struggling with performance.

I would be very grateful if someone can provide a fast solution and, if possible, to explain why is fast.

**EDIT**

Here is the *ugly* code, for my own embarrassment

```
rotZ = RotationTransform[{n, {0, 0, 1}}];
rotY = RotationTransform[{s, {0, 1, 0}}];
RT[v_]:= rotY[rotZ[-p + #]] & /@ v;
```

and then

```
dataTrans = RT /@ data
```

Taking

```
n = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
s = {-n[[2]], n[[1]], 0}; (* n and s are orthogonal *)
p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
```

then

```
Timing[RT /@ data][[1]]
(*    3.60422    *)
```

In an Intel Core2 Duo CPU T8100 @2.10GHz, 4gb ram Ubuntu 12.04, Mathematica 8 distribution.

Comment: It might help to post the code, "ugly" or not.

Comment: Are n,s,p already orthogonal?

Comment: `n` and `s` are.

Comment: There's an ampersand missing in the definition of RT

Comment: what is g? Perhaps it should be p?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks for *all* the debugging!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Defining n, s and p with their numeric values *before* defining the transformation function helps considerably, but a huge difference is made by changing the definition of RT to use the numerical matrices instead of the `RotationTransform`-s:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20000, 2, 3}];
n = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
s = {-n[[2]], n[[1]], 0};(*n and s are orthogonal*)
p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
rotZ = RotationTransform[{n, {0, 0, 1}}];
rotY = RotationTransform[{s, {0, 1, 0}}];

m = TransformationMatrix[rotY][[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]].TransformationMatrix[
     rotZ][[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]];

RT1[v_] := m.(-p + #) & /@ v;
RT2[v_] := rotY[rotZ[-p + #]] & /@ v;

Timing[r1 = RT1 /@ data][[1]]
Timing[r2 = RT2 /@ data][[1]]
```

> 0.328
>
> 2.824

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I didn't know that one could extract the numerical matrix from `RotationTransform`. Is there any difference (qualitatively) than simply use `RotationMatrix`?

Comment: Let `RT3[segs_] := Transpose[m.(Transpose[segs, {3, 2, 1}] - p), {3, 2, 1}]` and `data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {200000, 2, 3}]`. The timing for `RT1 /@ data` is 3.156 seconds; for `RT3[data]` (using efficient multithreaded `Transpose` and `Dot`) it is a matter of milliseconds.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I _suspected_ the `(-p + #) & /@` approach was inefficient, but I didn't know how else to do the sum. Can you explain why the program can do the sum when dimensions are `{3,2,N}` but it can't when they are `{N,2,3}`?

Comment: @Manuel that's just the way *Mathematica* is--which is my way of saying I don't know. Personally, I'd find exhaustive array broadcasting rules (like one finds in NumPy) very useful, but for whatever reason there hasn't been much effort in this direction. There are only so many features WRI can work on at once, I suppose, and `Transpose` usually gets the job done after all.